# React Navigation V6 Bottom Tab Not Displaying

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm following the guide [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens) from React Navigation V6 and my component is not displaying as it is intended to. When I swap out `createBottomTabNavigator`  with `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` I get my display. Can somebody help me figure out why the output is behaving this way? Photos are attached below the code. Thank you to anybody that can help!

Edit: React-Native-Web sometimes displays things incorrectly. When viewed on a phone it looks correct.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function FeedScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Feed Screen!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeScreen({ navigation }:any) {
  return (
    <View >
      <Text>Home screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Profile"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
      />
      <Button
        title="Go to Settings"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }:any) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Notifications Screen</Text>

    </View>
  );
}

function ProfileScreen({ navigation }:any) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Profile Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Settings"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen({ navigation }:any) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to tabs"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function BasicStack() {
  return (
  <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{ headerShown: true }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <BasicStack/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

[Output with `createBottomTabNavigator`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quqS9.png)

[Output with `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Tgq7.png)

Comment: Is there an error or does it just display incorrectly? It could be a bug in the library